# How to delete multiple rows without a loop in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Frequently we are asked how to delete rows based on criteria in one or more columns, and can we use a SpecialCells trick for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let me say categorically that **there is nothing wrong with loops** - they certainly have their place!

Recently we were presented with the below situation:

```
400000  |  Smith, John| 2.4   | 5.66|   =C1+D1
400001  |  Q, Suzy    | 4.6   | 5.47|   =C2+D2
400002  |  Schmoe, Joe| 3.8   | 0.14|   =C3+D3
Blank   |             |       |     |   #VALUE
Blank   |             |       |     |   #VALUE
```

The OP wanted to delete rows where Column A is blank, but there is a value in Column E.

I suggest that this is an example where we could make use of SpecialCells and a temporary *Error Column* to identify the rows to be deleted.

Consider that you might add a column H to try and identify those rows; in that row you could use a formula like below:

```
=IF(AND(A:A="",E:E<>""),"DELETE THIS ROW","LEAVE THIS ROW")
```

now, it is possible get that formula to put an error in the rows where I test returns True. The reason we would do this is a feature of Excel called SpecialCells.

In Excel select any empty cell, and in the formula bar type

```
=NA()
```

Next, hit F5 or CTRL+G (*Go to...* on the **Edit** menu) then click the *Special* button to show the SpecialCells dialog.

In that dialog, click the radio next to 'Formulas' and underneath, clear the checkboxes so that only **Errors** is selected. Now click OK

Excel should have selected all the cells in the worksheet with an Error (**#N/A**) in them.

The code below takes advantage of this trick by creating a formula in column H that will put an **#N/A** in all the rows you want to delete, then calling SpecialCells to find the rows, and clear (delete) them...

```
    Sub clearCells()
    '
    Dim sFormula As String
    '
    ' this formula put's an error if the test returns true, 
    ' so we can use SpecialCells function to highlight the
    ' rows to be deleted!
```

Create a formula that will return **#NA** when the formula returns TRUE

```
sFormula = "=IF(AND(A:A="""",E:E<>""""),NA(),"""")"
```

Put that formula in Column H, to find the rows that are to be deleted...

```
Range("H5:H" & Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = sFormula
```

Now use SpecialCells to highlight the rows to be deleted:

```
Range("H5:H" & Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).entirerow.select
```

This line of code would highlight just Column A by using **OFFSET** in case instead of deleting the entire row, you wanted to put some text in, or clear it

```
Range("H5:H" & Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Offset(0, -7).select
```

and the below line of code will delete thhe entire row **because we can :)**

```
Range("H5:H" & Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlup

' clean up the formula
Range("H5:H" & Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row).Clear
'
End Sub
```

BTW, it's also possible **WITH A LOOP** if you really want one :)

**One more thing, before Excel 2010 there was a limit of 8192 rows** (I think because this feature *went all the way back to 8-bit versions of Excel maybe*)

The VBA legend Ron de Bruin (on whose website I first picked up this technique, among others) [has something to say about this](http://www.rondebruin.nl/specialcells.htm)

Philip

Comment: Instead of iteratively updating sheet with a loop, iteratively build a range reference, then update sheet once using range. Much quicker code.


Loops are straightforward and useful, but in cases where physical changes are made to a worksheet, looping (*especially* through large datasets) can be immensely slower than a single call to change a sheet's contents. It's less straightforward to code, but using a loop to instead generate a range variable, and then using that to delete rows with one call provides much more efficient code while accomplishing the exact same conditional results.

Answer (score 8):

This will delete row numbers m to n passed through the function

```
Sub Delete_Multiple_Rows (m as Integer, n as Integer) 

    Rows(m & ":" & n).EntireRow.Delete 

End Sub
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use auto filters:

```
Sub clearCells()
'
' Example code for StackOverflow post
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431801/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-without-a-loop-in-excel-vba
'
Dim rngTable As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim StartCell As Range

Const ColumntoFilter1 As Integer = 1
Const FilterCriteria1 As String = "="
Const ColumntoFilter2 As Integer = 5
Const FilterCriteria2 As String = "<>"

Set ws = ActiveSheet
'Set the starting position (Top-left most position) of your data range
Set StartCell = ws.Range("A1")

'Turn off autofilter in case it's already active
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
'Define data table
Set rngTable = StartCell.CurrentRegion
'Filter and delete data
With rngTable
    .AutoFilter Field:=ColumntoFilter1, Criteria1:=FilterCriteria1
    .AutoFilter Field:=ColumntoFilter2, Criteria1:=FilterCriteria2
    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
End With

'Turn filters off again
ws.AutoFilterMode = False

Set rngTable = Nothing
Set StartCell = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: SpecialCells are redundant in this code. You can simply delete the filtered range as the hidden rows will not be touched.

Comment: It is used `Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: brettdj is correct - it is redundant.  Removed the redundancy.  Not sure why I added it.  May have been an artifact from reading the original post.