# Deleting rows in excel using VBA depending on values found using a formula

Tags: excel, vba

Hey guys I am trying to write a code that deletes rows having values that are found using a formula. The problem is every other row is a `#VALUE!`, which I cannot change due to the setup of the report. In the end I want to delete all rows that have `#VALUE!` and any row that has values that are less than .75 in `Column H`.

The code I tried is as shown below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, del As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("H1:H2000"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    For Each cell In rng
        If (cell.Value) < .75 Then
            If del Is Nothing Then
                Set del = cell
            Else: Set del = Union(del, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    On Error Resume Next
    del.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use a loop. Use an autofilter. Here is an example of [using an autofilter instead of a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16901714/138938). It is much more efficient.

Comment: @HeadofCatering or use my more efficient row deletion sub ;)

Comment: @mehow, it is somewhat more efficient, but you are still using a loop. The autofilter is a set-based operation, while the loop is comparable to iterating through the rows of a SQL resultset with a cursor.

Comment: @HeadofCatering set-based approach is **almost** always the best one to choose. yeah, almost :) ok, lets not debate here

Comment: my 2 cents folks, use `SpecialCells` **OR** `AutoFilter` as in [StackOverFlow: how-to-delete-multiple-rows-without-a-loop-in-excel-vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431801/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-without-a-loop-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my code is an alternative to the other answers, its much more efficient and executes faster then deleting each row separately :) give it a go

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i&, lr&, rowsToDelete$, lookFor$, lookFor2$

    '*!!!* set the condition for row deletion
    lookFor = "#VALUE!"
    lookFor2 = "0.75"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim arr(0)

    For i = 1 To lr
     If StrComp(CStr(ws.Range("H" & i).Text), lookFor, vbTextCompare) = 0 Or _
        CDbl(ws.Range("H" & i).Value) < CDbl(lookFor2) Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
        arr(UBound(arr) - 1) = i
     End If
    Next i

    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            rowsToDelete = rowsToDelete & arr(i) & ":" & arr(i) & ","
        Next i

        ws.Range(Left(rowsToDelete, Len(rowsToDelete) - 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "No more rows contain: " & lookFor & "or" & lookFor2 & ", therefore exiting"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not Application.ScreenUpdating Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 nice and elegant, might I suggest you try: `ws.Range(Left(rowsToDelete, Len(rowsToDelete) - 1)).Delete Shift:=xlUp` to avoid using `Selection`?

Comment: @Philip that's what I normally do and use but I wanted the selection to stand out in this example for an easier analysis of the code and its purpose. good comment thought I should have mentioned this in my answer as well

Comment: another alternative as the OP is to use `SpecialCells` to return the range to be deleted in one step (same for the *value <0.75* except you'd add another formula column returning an `#NA` error which can be found by **SpecialCells**)

Comment: ... something like Column X: 'Formula=IF(OR(VAL(H:H)<0.75,H:H="#VALUE"),"NA()","")` then `range("X:X").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).entirerow.delete shift:=xlup`

Comment: @Philip i think that would refer to what HeadOfCatering mentioned. Feel free to post your solution for an upvote! :)

Comment: just a quick note on a problem i ran into using this nice approach: rowsToDelete must not exceed 255 characters, otherwise range cannot handle it. you can work around this limitation by using union. i ended up putting a delimiter into the string each time it got to 255 characters (or a multiple of it), then i split it and put the parts together via union which worked out fine (i also did not use an array, but put the string directly together to avoid the redim).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest stepping backwards through the rows so that when a row is deleted you don't lose your place.

Assuming that you want to look at cells contained in column H you could do something like this:

```
Sub Example()
    Const H As Integer = 8
    Dim row As Long

    For row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        On Error Resume Next
        If Cells(row, H).Value < 0.75 Then
            Rows(row).Delete
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, del As Range, v As Variant
Set rng = Intersect(Range("H1:H2000"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
For Each cell In rng
    v = cell.Text
    If v < 0.75 Or v = "#VALUE!" Then
        If del Is Nothing Then
            Set del = cell
        Else: Set del = Union(del, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
On Error Resume Next
del.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: are you comparing v (String) against 0.75 without casting? hows that gonna work

Comment: Since v is a Variant, seems to work O.K.