# Deleting rows with specific words with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

currently my excel data consists of specific words and #N/A, words are like "build One" "proj ex".. I have prepared a code in which it only deletes one condition but I want it for many words. below is my code. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

```
Sub del()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range([B2], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
With rng1
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:=("#N/A")
.Delete xlUp
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You could create an array of all words you want, then loop the array. #

Comment: Hey Paul, I am new to VBA, will be great if you can give me an e.g of it looping it in array.

Comment: @Kiran: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vba+loop+through+array

Answer (score 4):

Use a variant array as a constructor for your word list.

```
Sub del()
    Dim rng1 As Range, vDELs As Variant

    vDELs = Array("#N/A", "proj ex", "build One")
    Set rng1 = Range([B2], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    With rng1
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(vDELs), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        With .Offset(1, 0)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then _
                .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

Good catch on bracketing the array in `Criteria1:=(vDELs)`. That is important. Also a good idea to check if you have rows to delete before committing to the operation.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped for going through it. What does If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) do ? and 103 is constant ?

Comment: @Kiran - The worksheet [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) does not count hidden values so if it counts anything it will return a non-zero which `CBool` interprets as *True*. The **103** is the designation for Subtotal to act as CountA. See the supplied link for more info.

Comment: Many Thanks Jeeped, That helps. code works perfectly. Have a nice day ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like:

```
sFormula = "=IF(OR(ISERROR(B:B),B:B=""proj ex"", B:B=""build One""),NA(),"""")"

Set rng1 = Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
rng1.Formula = sFormula
```

' Now use SpecialCells to remove the rows:

```
rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
```

more on this type of technique at [SO: How to delete multiple rows in Excel without a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431801/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-without-a-loop-in-excel-vba) and [Ron de Bruin Excel VBA Top Banana: Special Cells limit bug](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win003.htm)