# Match value from sheet 1 A column to sheet 2 A column and delete the row if A value is not found

Tags: vba, excel

The line `Set fn = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(Range.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)` is giving me error:

> "Argument not optional" on "Range.Value".

I want the code to move from last row to the top. Looking at Sheet1's column A's value. Then search for it in Sheet2's A column and if it is there then delete the entire row on Sheet 1. However I cant figure out the syntax/issues or is there better way to rewrite that line?

Full code(Edited):

```
Sub Isitthere()
    Dim c As Long, LR As Long
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, fn As Range
    Set sh1 = Application.Sheets("Current") 'Edit sheet name
    Set sh2 = Application.Sheets("MTD") 'Edit sheet name
    LR = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For c = LR To 2 Step -1
        Set fn = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(sh1.Cells(c, 1).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not fn Is Nothing Then
                sh1.Cells(c.Row, Columns.Count).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question and be sure to ask a [good, clear, concise question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion),  include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: have a look at [How to delete multiple rows without a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431801/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-without-a-loop-in-excel-vba/15431802#15431802) - you can just create a formula to mark rows as **deletable** then delete them, then remove the formula column

Comment: also, what is `Range.Value` in `Set fn = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(Range.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)`

Comment: I guess that's where i stuck on how to write the code. I basically want the line to say "If you can not find the A1/2/3/4/etc value in sheet 2 column A then mark it as "Nothing" so the If statement below that will delete the entire row.

Comment: have a look at my answer in [How to delete multiple rows without a loop in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431801/how-to-delete-multiple-rows-without-a-loop-in-excel-vba/15431802#15431802)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range.Value` (which is really `Range().Value`) isn't valid syntax because `Range()` is expecting an argument, and you're giving it none, which gives `.Find` an invalid argument as well.

`Range.Value` should either be `sh1.Cells(c, 1).Value` or `sh1.Range("A" & c).Value`.

Comment: After i changed that it is giving me "Invalid qualifier" for the line `sh1.Cells(c.Row, Columns.Count).EntireRow.Delete`. I believe it is the `(c.Row, Columns.Count)` part.
I edited the full code with your suggestion for ease of viewing.

Comment: Change that to `sh1.Cells(c, 1).EntireRow.Delete`. Or `sh1.Rows(c).Delete`